# Work with content wrapped with Scrolloverflow.js + Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I use Fullpage.js together with Scrolloverflow plugin for my template:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    scrollOverflow: true,
    afterRender: function() {
        $("nav").on("click", "a", function() {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

On the official website they say that I need to use delegation in order to work with content wrapped by the Scrolloverflow plugin. However, it doesn't seem to work in my case, because the `click` event doesn't work in my example. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle example so we could play around?

Comment: Sorry, I failed to find CDN for scrolloverflow.js

Comment: As I understand scrolloverflow is part of slimScroll https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jQuery-slimScroll

Comment: No, it's a modified version of iScroll https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/

Comment: Instead of loading it as cdn you can also paste the code inside script tag https://jsfiddle.net/1kh1rnye/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the latest fullpage.js version? 2.8.1? That should work on desktops.

[There's a known issue with iScroll.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2035) that affect mobile devices.

Comment: it actually happened when I updated to 2.8.1. I tried to set click: true, but it didn't solve the issue on desktop.

Comment: Had to set it to false instead to make it work. Need some more testing though.

Comment: @Deka87 `click` is already `true` in fullpage.js 2.8.1. And that's suppose to solve the problem in desktops as pointed out [here](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/783). In fact, you can test it [on this codepen](http://codepen.io/sjaakbanaan/pen/GqgZjK) where click event works.

Comment: On the codepen you provided it is set to click: false. Same as I did to make it work on desktops. I wonder why it is set to true by default.

Comment: @Deka87 good point. True. This an issue of iScroll.js... but it seems its developer is not very keen on solving it..